# What is wrong with this perl associative array?

Tags: perl

## script A

```
use strict;

our %pre_pkg_configs;

$pre_pkg_configs{locDbList}={qw(default default_test)};
```

## script B

//load script A

```
my @locDbNames = ();

foreach my $dbName ($pre_pkg_configs{"locDbList"}){
  print $dbName;
  push(@locDbNames,$dbName);
}
```

## output

```
HASH(0x119b368)
```

I was expecting values : default default_test

Comment: If you're learning Perl from a reference that uses the term "associative array" then you should throw it away. Perl replaced that term with "hash" when Perl 5 was released in 1994.

Comment: @DaveCross, coming from php, its hard to grasp the concepts.Its my fault :)

Comment: `foreach my $dbName (%$pre_pkg_configs{"locDbList"})` you miss '%' as de-reference of hash-reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{ ... }` creates a reference to a hash (what you are calling an associative array).

If you print a reference, you get output like `HASH(0x119b368)`

It sounds like you want an array, so use an arrayref instead of a hashref:

```
$pre_pkg_configs{locDbList}=[ qw(default default_test) ];
```

Then, when printing it, you need to convert the arrayref into an array:

```
foreach my $dbName (@{$pre_pkg_configs{"locDbList"}}){
```

Comment: how do I print each element in the array ? or how to assign the array to a local variable e.g `my @locDbNames=()`

Comment: You weren't - you were looping over a list consisting of a single array ref. I've edited the answer to deference the array there instead.